# Creating a method to be called on an array

Tags: ruby, oop

`test_cal` is an instance of a custom class and `get_calendar_items` returns an array. I want to write a method to be called on an array like so:

```
test_cal.get_calendar_items.get_subject
```

Here is the method I wrote

```
def get_subject(number)
    puts self[number].subject
end
```

However, ruby gives an error:

```
undefined method get_subject for #<Array:0x00 ...> (NoMethodError)
```

How do I write a method that can be called on an array?

I assumed each array is some kind of object.
The individual elements of the array are then accessed in the method via `number`.

Comment: Where is `number` coming from? You don't give it to `get_subject` when you call it. Shouldn't you say `test_cal.get_calendar_items.get_subject(number)`? And then why not just do `test_cal.get_calendar_items[number].subject` instead? That's the normal way. And shorter.

Comment: It's unidiomatic to prefix getters with `get_` in Ruby. Just call the method `calendar_items` or simply `items`.

Comment: An array is a collection of _arbitrary_ objects. It therefore doesn't make much sense to add a method that only works for specific elements (and you don't have to, as shown by Stefan Pochmann above). A better approach would be to create a custom class for your collection (e.g. `CalenderItemArray`) or to `extend` the array instances returned by `get_calendar_items`, so you only add the "collection methods" to those arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define it in the Array class

```
class Array
  def get_subject(number)
      puts self[number].subject
  end
end
```

Since you're new to Ruby, you should know that this approach is not very good since it depends greatly on what objects are being stored in the array. For example I can do `[1].get_subject(0)` or `["foo"].get_subject(0)` and I'll get an error because numbers and strings don't have a `subject` method.

Comment: If taking this approach I would modify line 3 to puts self[number].subject if self[number].is_a?('CalendarItem')

Comment: Replacing an error with `nil` does not fix the problem. Don't worry too much about it for now since you're just getting started, but there are much more idiomatic ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Altough you could define an `Array` instance method in order to solve your issue, defining a method of a Core class is considered a bad practice for many reasons. Better is f.e. to define another method within `test_cal` class which fetches `subject` from `get_calendar_items`:

```
class TestCal # or whichever `test_cal` class is
  def get_calendar_items_subjects
    get_calendar_items.map &:subject
  end
end
```

And then:

```
test_cal.get_calendar_items_subjects[number]
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would only extend Array if it was a method that could be called on all arrays. Due to the subject being a prerequisite method on the array contents, I would think adding a class method like the following would be better.

```
class CalendarItem
  def self.get_subject(arr, index=0)
    arr[index].subject
  end
end
```

Reorganized code would read

```
CalendarItem.get_subject(test_cal.get_calendar_items)
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann I apologize, I did not catch that the post was not specific to Rails. Nice catch. Solution amended.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_subject(number)
  puts self[number].subject
end
```

Simply you can call your above method as below :

```
test_cal.get_calendar_items.each do |number|
  get_subject(number)
end
```